# Ping Equivalent For Checking If A Port Is Open

Tags: monitoring, ping, network-monitoring, uptime

How do I check if a port is consistently alive? For example, I could use

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -t > results.txt
```

This will ping 192.168.1.1 continuously so that I could monitor it.
Is there an equivalent tool or command that I could use for this?

Currently I use telnet but sometimes the host disconnects it. I need a Windows solution.

Comment: Is it a specific port you need to check e.g. port 80 for http or port 21 for ftp, or is it a specific IP address you need to check i.e. to test if the host is reachable. The latter is what your above example is doing.

Comment: i'm wanting to check a specific port if it is open.

Comment: Since "standard" ping uses ICMP messages, and when talking about ports you probably think about TCP/IP, you have a mismatch there that you can not close (ICMP and IP are very different protocols). `ping` is the wrong tool for monitoring, you should use something that generates the kind of traffic you need for the specific service. Example: to monitor a website you send an HTTP query, etc.

Answer (score 13):

You could use netcat if there is a Windows version - on Linux I use:

```
nc -z <host> <port>
```

This returns 0 if the port is open. Run this in a loop for make it continuous.

If Powershell is available, see https://web.archive.org/web/20111102182913/http://poshcode.org/85 for an example.

Comment: ping every second a host on a port and return `0` if successfully so, `1` else: `while (:); do nc -z HOSTNAME_HERE PORT_HERE; echo $?; sleep 1; done`

Comment: link doesnt work anymore

Comment: @ClintonWard Updated with an archived link :)

Answer (score 5):

Or use nmap from http://nmap.org , there is a windows version available.

nmap -p port host

or, for hosts not responding to ICMP requests,

nmap -P0 -p port host

Answer (score 5):

You could use nping from nmap like:

```
C:\>nping --tcp -p 80 192.168.1.1
```

where `-p` specifies the port to scan (here: 80).
Furthermore you can use `-H` for hiding sent packets, in favor of showing only replies.

Answer (score 0):

telnet `<host> <port>` will check remote `<host>` for a TCP listener on `<port>`.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to go with stock command line utils,** then [TELNET will connect to a port](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?telnet) for you. On the flip side, if there is service responding, then TELNET may 'hang' while waiting for you to supply the escape command sequence.

**If you're open to installing new command line utils,** then [PaPing works as you want](http://code.google.com/p/paping/). It's cross platform, and there is a Windows installer available.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Download nmap command line tools from nmap.org, there you will find ncat.
Copy and paste this text and to text editor and save as .BAT-file

```
@Echo Off
REM *************************************************************************
REM ** Port tester for Service Uptime Logging using NCAT.EXE from nmap.org **
REM **                                                                     **
REM ** Static variables:                                                   **
REM ** Host_IP = Hostname or IP you want to test                           **
REM ** Host_Port = Port number service are listening to                    **
REM ** LogFileName = Name of Logfile                                       **
REM ** WaitTime = Ca. number of seconds between each query                 **
REM *************************************************************************

:Pre
SET Host_IP=127.15.4.75
SET Host_Port=80
SET LogFileName=Ncat_%Host_IP%_%Host_Port%.txt
SET WaitTime=10

:Start
ping 127.15.4.75 -w 1000 -n %WaitTime% > NUL
ncat -z %Host_IP% %Host_Port% >NUL
if errorlevel=2 Goto Error2
if errorlevel=1 Goto Error1
if errorlevel=0 Goto Error0
Goto Start

:Error2
Echo %time% Other Error >> %LogFileName%
Goto Start

:Error1
Echo %time% Network Error >> %LogFileName%
Goto Start

:Error0
Echo %time% Connection successful >> %LogFileName%
Goto Start
:End
```